# How can i know if a list is decreasing? (Python)

Tags: python, list, boolean

I am new to python and I have to do an exercise for classes. The exercises asks me to make a function which tells weather a list given is ordered decreasing or not (Giving back True or False)
I tried the following code:

```
def no_decreasing(list):
    for num in len(list):
        if list[num] <= list[num+1]:
            check = bool(1)
        else:
            check = bool(0)
            break
    return check
```

It gives back an te error "int" object is not iterable in line 2, does anyone know why?

Comment: You probably don't want a variable name called *list*. What would the return value be if the list had less than two elements?

Comment: `all(a >= b for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:]))` where `nums` would be what you call `list` but that is very bad practice to overwrite builtins.

Comment: You probably meant to use a `range()` in that for-loop:  `for num in range(len(list))`.  The `for` statement expects an iterable (e.g. list, range, etc.) not a simple number.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: don't use `list` as the parameter name (it's a builtin type), use something else.  I'll use `nums` as the place of the list parameter rather than `list`.*

The expression `for num in len(nums)` doesn't work because `len(nums)` is a single int.  What you would want instead is `for num in nums` (which would iterate over each number in `nums`, or `for index in len(range(nums))` (which would iterate over each valid index into `nums`).

Other options:

- `for i, num in enumerate(nums)` -- `i` is the index, `num` is the value.
- `for num1, num2 in zip(nums, nums[1:])` -- `num1` and `num2` are two successive values from `nums`, obtained by `zip`ping `nums` with a shifted version of itself.

*Additional note: when you need a boolean literal, instead of `bool(1)` and `bool(0)` just use `True` and `False`!*

You could also shortcut the entire problem by sorting the list in decreasing order and seeing if it's the same as the original list:

```
def is_decreasing(nums):
    return nums == sorted(nums, reverse=True)
```

Comment: I now realise, but i can´t do anything about the list name, it´s set in the exercise and we can´t change the name, whatever. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Well you are trying to iterate over indeces, so

```
for i in range(len(lst)):  # never use "list" as a variable name
```

or rather

```
for i in range(len(lst)-1):  # to avoid an index error for its right neighbor
```

would be appropriate. However, a better way would use `zip`

```
def non_decreasing(lst):
    for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if b < a:
            return False
    return True
```

A short-hand for that pattern is `any` or `all`:

```
def non_decreasing(lst):
    return all(a <= b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
    # return not any(b < a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the index in the `for` loop, but you've made a semantic mistake:

```py
for num in len(list):
   # This does not work. It can not iterate through an integer.
```

`len()` function returns an integer. Your basically saying `for num in 10`, say if the list has 10 numbers.

What you want is the `range` function:

```py
for num in range(0, len(list)):
```

This will loop from `num=0` to `num=0+len(list)-1`.

Be careful though with `if list[num] <= list[num+1]:`, as the previous approach will make that line search for an index greater them your array size. As such, this is how you could fix your code:

```py
for num in range(0, len(list)-1):
```

P.S.: There are other ways to solve that issue, but since it is a class exercise, I've focused on solving the issue you've had when iterating through an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out using `zip(lst, lst[1:])`. This is undesirable for large lists, though, since you first have to make a copy of `lst` (minus the first element) before `zip` can produce the pairwise iterator that the `for` loop uses.

Instead, use two separate iterators, advancing the second one before passing it to `zip`.

```
def no_decreasing(lst):
    i1 = iter(lst)
    i2 = iter(lst)
    next(i2)

    return all(a >= b for a, b in zip(i1, i2))
    # Or you can use map
    # return all(map(operator.ge, i1, i2))
```